# Find expectations of functions of random variables

Tags: probability

So I have this problem I've been stuck on..

> If $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1/2$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 0.6$, then find:
>
> $$\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X}]\text{ and }\mathbb{E}[X(X-1)]$$

Now I know that
$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int x \  \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}$ and that $\mathbb{E} [X^2] = \int x^2 \ \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}$

And that

$\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X}] = \int \sqrt{x}\ \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}$

But I've been trying to find a relationship between all 4 but I couldn't.. Help would be appreciated

Comment: Note that $E(X(X-1))=E(X^2-X)=E(X^2)-E(X)=0.6-\frac{1}{2}$. But without further information about $X$ I cannot find $E(\sqrt{X})$.

Comment: The above comment is correct. Also, to the OP, try not to confuse the random variable $X$ (which is a function on events) and the values $x$ which the random variable $X$ can take (which are often real numbers). Also I wrote the definitions of expectation using the most general possible notation for integration with respect to an arbitrary probability measure in the Lebesgue sense, since you did not specify whether the random variable $X$ is discrete or continuous, i.e. I used the definition of expectation which is more abstract but applicable to both of the two common cases.